# Android 3D navigation menu drawer

Tags: android-navigation

I'm trying to implement a navigation menu drawer on home screen action bar icon at top.  When a user taps the top header icon, home screen ie. landing screen of the the app to right end of the screen with re-sized height with 3D effect.Below the screenshots for your reference. Let me know your valuable suggestions to implement the same.

[image: Home Screen]

[image: Navigation menu drawer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not an easy way to do this with straight view animations, which is what the `FragmentTransaction` methods for custom animations or the `Activity` override animation method uses.  The rotation property is 2D, so it will rotate both X and Y axis.

Answer (score 3):

You can use library to create 3-D effect:

https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMeun

you can also use some new libraries as well:

https://github.com/shiburagi/Drawer-Behavior?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6239